# Tcpdf подключить кириллицу

Tags: pdf, tcpdf, php

Проблема такая: хоть убейте, но не могу сделать так, чтобы в пдф отражались русские буквы. Может, кто скинет ссылку, где написано для чайников, как сделать (правда, я уже весь гугл облазил), или сможет написать, как это сделать?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Проверьте справедливость следующих пунктов:

1. Вы используете unicode (**true**).
2. Вы используете нужную кодировку (**UTF-8**).
3. Вы используете шрифт, поддерживающий кириллицу (**dejavusans**).

   ```
   $pdf = new TCPDF('P', 'mm', 'A4', true, 'UTF-8');
   $pdf->SetFont('dejavusans', '', 14, '', true);
   $pdf->AddPage();
   $pdf->writeHTML('corresponding content', true, false, false, false, '');
   $pdf->Output('output.pdf', 'D');
   ```